# topology of compact convergence, closed sets

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $H(\mathbb{D})$ be the vector space of all analytic functions on the unit disk. Then the topology induced by uniform convergence on compact subsets is metrizable.

Thus the following topology should be equivalent: A $\subset H(\mathbb{D})$ is closed iff $[f_n \in A, f_n \mbox{ converges uniformly on compact subsets to } f\in H(\mathbb{D}) \Rightarrow f \in A].$

This might seem trivial, but I really need to be sure since no one seems to define it like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Merely saying that $A$ is closed iff $\bar{A} = A$.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? $A$ is closed in my alternative topology iff the closure of $A$ in the topology of compact convergence equals $A$? That would translate to: $A$ is closed in my alternative topology iff $A$ is closed in the topology of compact convergence, and that is my question...so I don't see your point